# New question(s) indicator in browser tab doesn't disappear

Tags: bug, new-nav

When I click the "new questions" indicator when watching a tag to load the newest question

[image: New questions!]

It doesn't remove the notification that appears in the browser tab

[image: New?!]

This is very confusing when the tab isn't active in the browser and I see this notification.

Comment: Yup, it regressed. It was broken at the start, then fixed, now back. I've re-opened my original post and poked the developer responsible.